# MPDF with code igniter not working on server

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, pdf, server, mpdf

I'm currently trying to generate a PDF using the mpdf library with code igniter. When I load the function on localhost it works fine but when I put it on my ubuntu server all I'm getting is a 404 error.

Anyone know whats causing this?

Controller:

```
function generatePDF(){
    $htmlOut = 'Some html code';

    include("third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php");

    $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0);

    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlOut);

    $mpdf->Output("filename.pdf",'I');

}
```

Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: Replace this `include("third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php");` line with this `require_once APPPATH."/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php";` and check.

Comment: Still getting a 404 unfortunately @RajJagani , Any other ideas?

Comment: Add **D** parameter instead of **I** in your mpdf output means `$mpdf->Output("filename.pdf",'D');`

Comment: Still the same result @RajJagani , its almost as if it can't find the function but its the correct name and everything, as I said its working locally. I can't figure it out for the life of me ..

Comment: set `$mpdf->debug = true;` and check you are getting any error and also please put browser console error if any.

Comment: Still getting a 404 .. It doesn't seem to even run the function to actually get any errors.. the console is also just showing a 404 error, I appreciate the help by the way! @RajJagani

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my controller name was all lower case letters and the first letter needs to be uppercase for the controller to actually work when put on server!